# Completetion of Banach spaces for uncountable index

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $I$ be an index set, and $V_i$ is a collection of Banach spaces. Consider $p < \infty$, I know that $\sum V_i$ is may not complete under the norm $$||f|| := \left(\sum ||\pi_i(f)||^p\right)^{1/p}$$I know the completion would be functions $f \in \prod V_i$ such that $\sum ||\pi_i(f)||^p < \infty$. This makes complete sense if $I$ is countable since I can just think of $\sum$ as a sequence, but what confuses me is if $I$ is just an index or uncountable(at least what that would look like).

Comment: A point in $\sum_i V_i$ is a function from $I$ to the union $\bigcup_i V_i$ where $f(i) = 0_i \in V_i$ for all but finitely many $i$. If you consider a (Cauchy) sequence $f^n \in \sum V_i$, then there will only be countably many pairs $(n, i) \in \Bbb{N} \times I$ such that $f^n(i) \neq 0_i$. Essentially, sequences always exist in a countable sub-sum, so your intuition about countable sums and sequences will extend to the uncountable case pretty well.